# More than 1 widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Following is my code

```
$op=array("description"=>"Ads Widget");
    wp_register_sidebar_widget('adswidget','Ads','ads_widget',$op);
    register_widget_control('adswidget','ads_widget_control');
```

I can use only 1 Ads Widget. I want to use more than 1 Ads Widget ? How to write it ? I'm finding in google and still not found.

Still not found document on

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_sidebar_widget

also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all widgets that are created using the [widgets api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins/WordPress_Widgets_Api) are multi instance.

The code you have above is the old method before WordPress 2.8.  Now you just need to extend the widget class and add some functions.  Default Example:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
function My_Widget() {
    // widget actual processes
}

function form($instance) {
    // outputs the options form on admin
}

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    // processes widget options to be saved
}

function widget($args, $instance) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
}

}
register_widget('My_Widget');
```

See Codex Page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins/WordPress_Widgets_Api

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution above as it's much simpler and easier to implement, but here is another method of multi-widgets which sort of provides a behind the scenes look as well...

http://justcoded.com/article/wordpress-multi-widgets/